# joining two intermediate files file1.csv and file2.csv in unix. Not getting desired format

Tags: unix

I am trying to join two intermediate files in UNIX

```
i.e file1.csv and file2.csv
```

I am using the below command to join the two files-

```
join --nocheck-order -t, -1 1 -2 1 ${DataDir}/FILE1.CSV ${DataDir}/FILE2.CSV > ${DataDir}/FILE1_FILE2.CSV -a1
```

But I am not getting the desired output format [file1 & file2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUHUJ.png)

I have attched the file1 and file2 format and also the desired output file and the file which is getting generated
[desired & actual file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxE5Q.png)

Can anybody help on this?

Comment: Hi Michael,beg your pardon.I uploaded a wrong format earlier for File 1.Now I uploaded the correct one.

Comment: Don't make us chase links: put your input and output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `-o 0,1.1,1.2,1.3` to your command

By the way, why do you need the `join` if your desired result file is the same as the first one?

Comment: Hi Michael,beg your pardon.I uploaded a wrong format earlier for File 1.Now I uploaded the correct one.

Comment: Then change the addition to `-o 0,1.1,1.2,2.2`. In short, the `-o` controls your out. Fit it to your needs.